# import contribution

Tags: import, contributions

I try to import contribution.
Procedure
 - Contribution
 - import contribution
 - import the .csv list

Error "is not a valid option for field campaign_id"

Where do I find the campaign_id?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you contributions belong to a campaign, you can find out the id by visiting the campaign dashboard (/civicrm/campaign?reset=1) and hover over the edit link on the right side. You will see a link like the one below - the last number is your campaign ID.

/civicrm/campaign/add?reset=1&action=update&id=1

However, if your contributions do not belong to campaigns, I guess you would probably not have to set them when importing?

Comment: Indeed, if they don't belong to a campaign, you don't need to set this field.